# how to properly destroy an instance of MathLive.makeMathField

Tags: javascript, math

I create a field for editing in a modal window, I want to destroy an instance of MathLive when closing a modal

```
mounted() {
    mathField = MathLive.makeMathField(this.$refs.mathField, {
        virtualKeyboardMode: 'manual',
        onContentDidChange: (e) => {
            this.latex = e.element.mathfield.latex();
        }
    });
},
beforeDestroy() {
    // ????
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method to destroy the instance is `mathField.$revertToOriginalContent()`
This is an unexpected name.